# Designing a Data Access Class in Java

Tags: java

So I'm writing a REST Api and I've defined 1 service class for every resource.

Thus I've a Person resource and this is the way I'm interacting with the data base.

```
public class TeacherService {


    public static List<Person> getAll() throws SQLException{

        //define the query string and objects



        try{

                DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver ());
                connection = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(ConnectDb.CONN_STRING, ConnectDb.USERNAME, ConnectDb.PASSWORD);
                statement = (PreparedStatement) connection.prepareStatement(query, ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
                        ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
                resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);

                //process results

            }catch (SQLException e) {
                System.err.println(e);

            }finally{

                //close all shit
            }

        return list;
    }

    public static Person getById(int id) throws SQLException{
        //repeat
    }

    public static void addPerson(Person person) throws SQLException {

        //repeat
    }

    public static void upateTeacher(Person person) throws SQLException {


        //repeat
    }

    public static void deleteTeacher(int id) throws SQLException {


            //repeat        
    }


}
```

So except for the Query which is different in every case and the resultSet processing logic every thing is pretty much the same.
This not only violates DRY at many levels but also seems extremely unwieldy to maintain. Is there a better way to do it.

Comment: I'd recommend against opening a new connection --> running a query --> closing the connection, every time you want to query. Opening and closing will create a *lot* of overhead, and slow things down considerably. Instead, open the connection when you create a new TeacherService object,  and keep the connection open until you close/stop/destroy your TeacherService object. Re-use the connection. You can do the same with your PreparedStatements (ie. prepare them all on the open connection, and keep a reference to the created objects, allowing for rapid re-use).

Comment: Could you provide some code snippet, since the resultSets and statements are all different, which one do I close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of how you might go about it. This example isn't perfect, but should set you on the right path.

Essentially, you register all your statements after opening a common shared connection. Do all your work, then call the shutdown() method to close it all down.

```
public class MyDataAccessObject {

    private final String getAllPersonsQuery = "SELECT persons FROM personTable";
    private PreparedStatement psGetAllPersonsQuery;

    private final String addPersonQuery = "INSERT INTO personTable (personName) VALUES (?)"; // ? is a placeholder. Using PreparedStatement and ?'s, adds more safety and performance.
    private PreparedStatement psAddPersonQuery;

    private Connection conn;

    private final String connectionString;
    private final String username;
    private final String password;

    public MyDataAccessObject(String connectionString, String username, String password) {
        this.connectionString =  connectionString;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public void init() throws SQLException {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString, username, password); // no longer required to register driver if using modern JDBC drivers.
        psGetAllPersonsQuery = conn.prepareStatement(getAllPersonsQuery);
        psAddPersonQuery = conn.prepareStatement(addPersonQuery); // we register these now, so it's fast to use later.
    }

    public void shutdown() throws SQLException {
        if (conn != null) {
            conn.close(); // this will close everything used ontop of this connection, including PreparedStatement's, and ResultSets, if still open.
        }
    }

    public List<Person> getAllPersons() throws SQLException {
        if (conn == null) {
            // try to re-open connection
            init();
        }
        ResultSet rs = psGetAllPersonsQuery.execute();
        List<Person> list = new ArrayList<Person>();
        while (rs.next()) {
            list.add(new Person(rs.getString(1))); // not sure how your data is setup, this is returning the first (1) column from the resultset
        }
        if (rs != null) {
            rs.close();
        }
        return list;
    } // don't close the prepareStatement!

    public void addPerson(Person person) throws SQLException {
        if (conn == null) {
            // try to re-open connection
            init();
        }
        psAddPersonQuery.setString(1, person.getName()); // or however you're storing the data. The 1 is saying replace the first ? with whatever data you specify after the comma.
        psAddPersonQuery.executeUpdate(); // executeUpdate() returns an int, which says how many rows were modified. Since you're inserting here, we probably don't care.
    } // don't close the prepareStatement!

}
```

You would use it like:

```
MyDataAccessObject mdao = new MyDataAccessObject(connectionString, username, password);
mdao.init(); // now you're ready

List<Person> list = mdao.getAllPersons();
// do stuff with your list

....
mdao.addPerson(someNewPerson);
// ....

// now you're done running, so close it down
mdao.shutdown();
```

Comment: Thanks this is awesome.